# Unexpected behavior with multiple instances of Handsontable in a page

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a page with multiple instances of handsontable. All custom properties of a handsontable seems to be attached to the last rendered table. 
Is there anyway to get around this?

For Example in the image below while hovering on the top table, comments on the bottom table are shown

[image]

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd0fucct/2/)**

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getData() {
        return [
        ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"], ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13], ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13], ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]];
    }

    var container1 = document.getElementById('example1');
    var container2 = document.getElementById('example2');
    var options = {
        data: getData(),
        startRows: 5,
        startCols: 5,
        minRows: 5,
        minCols: 5,
        maxRows: 10,
        maxCols: 10,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        contextMenu: true,
        comments: true,
        cell: [{
            row: 1,
            col: 1,
            comment: "Test comment"
        }, {
            row: 2,
            col: 2,
            comment: "Sample"
        }]
    };
    var hot1 = Handsontable(container1, options);
    var hot2 = Handsontable(container2, options);
})
```

Comment: That's very strange behavior. Having more than one table seems to be an issue for me as well. But have you tried cloning the options object? Maybe it's copying the reference

Comment: @ZekeDroid that is not the problem. I tried it http://jsfiddle.net/yd0fucct/3/

Comment: I can't find the answer anywhere but I'm meddling with two tables on the same page again, will let you know if I figure something out. I wish there was a bigger community in stack using HOT, not enough fresh ideas yet

Comment: I actually made my own tooltip framework on top of this because my application can have an arbitrary number of HOT instances. I'll share the code soon

Comment: oh nice, I had resorted to using the native "Title" attributes on the divs

Comment: That's what i did as well. combined with bootstrap it gives you the tooltips :)

Comment: beautiful, looking forward

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by the Handsontable team.